# How to delete files with specific size?

Tags: command-line, delete, find

Using `ls -lSrh` I get this output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 2.4K Feb 15 04:44 10010.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 2.4K Feb 15 04:43 1000.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 2.4K Feb 15 04:44 10009.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 2.4K Feb 15 04:44 10008.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 2.4K Feb 15 04:43 10004.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 2.4K Feb 15 04:43 10000.png
```

How can I delete all `.png` files with the specific `2.4K` size?

Comment: Try `find` with condition `-size`. Print the file names first in order to check the result. If it matches your expectations, you can add the `-delete` action.

Answer (score 4):

[Bodo's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455268/delete-images-with-specific-size#comment2543389_1455268) points you at the right direction, but things are a bit trickier than they seem. That is because the file size you see in the `ls -lSrh` output is not the exact size of the files, but the file size in **human readable format**, due to the use of the `-h` flag. To use `find` to find the files of a specific file size, however, you need to know the **exact size** of the files, so you need to run the command:

```
ls -lSr
```

that is the `ls` command you used, but without the `-h` flag, which outputs file sizes in bytes.

If you run this command, then you will most likely find that all these files that previously seemed to all have the exact same size of `2.4K` have somewhat different sizes now. What you need to do is determine the lower and the upper file size limits of the files you want to delete and then run the following `find` command from within the directory your files are located in:

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.png" -size +<lower_limit>c -size -<upper_limit>c -delete
```

Explanation of the above command:

- `.`: search in the current directory.
- `-type f`: search for files only, not directories.
- `-name "*.png"`: search for files that their name ends with `.png`.
- `-size +<lower_limit>c -size -<upper_limit>c`: search for files with sizes between the `<lower_limit>` and `<upper_limit>`, in other words for files larger than the `<lower_limit>` (that's what `+` means) and lower than the `<upper_limit>` (that's what `-` means). The `c` suffix that follows `<lower_limit>` and `<upper_limit>` is used to tell `find` that the sizes are in bytes, which is what you get for the file sizes from `ls -lSr`.
- `-delete`: delete the found files that fulfill the above criteria.

---

**CAUTION:**

**First run the above command without `-delete` to make sure that it lists the correct files!** If you are satisfied with the output, then and only then add `-delete`!

The `-delete` action deletes the found files permanently, so you will not be able to recover them in case of a mistake. Always make sure to keep a backup of the original files in case something goes wrong.

---

**References:**

- [`man ls`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/ls.1.html)
- [`man find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: It might be more useful to use `find`'s own action `-ls` instead of `-delete` for a dry-run as it will show file sizes in an `ls` style output while the default `find`'s `-print` action won't.